# merge sub-array if other key-value pair match

Tags: javascript

I have this simple array, which I want to merge key `b` value if key `a` in the whole array matches.

```
const array = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Bar']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
]
```

into

```
const array = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo','Bar','Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
]
```

is there a way to do it? Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT 1 : What I am lacking here is the logic to grab all similar key `a`

Comment: What have you tried? [It might involve a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). Or [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) perhaps? Lots of questions on here about "grouping" things in arrays and objects.

Comment: I have tried `reduce()` and I am stuck for days on how to group similar key `a` up to concatenate key `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the array of objects to create an object where the keys match the object's `a` value, adding the various `b` values to their arrays. Then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to create a new array.

```js
const arr = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Bar']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
];

// For each iteration pass in the accumulator
// and the current object
const out = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Assign the value of `a` to `key`
  const key = c.a;
  
  // If the key doesn't exist on the accumulator
  // set a new object
  acc[key] = acc[key] || { a: key, b: [] };

  // And then push the first element of `b`
  // into the object's array
  acc[key].b.push(c.b[0]);

  // Return the accumulator
  return acc;

}, {});

// And then finally get the Object.values from
// your returned object to make an array
console.log(Object.values(out));
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. An alternate approach (without `reduce`) may be to pick-out the unique `a` values into an array and simply iterate over the input-array adding each a-b pair into an object.

Comment: Yeah @jsN00b I did think about that but then I'd probably have to get into the mechanics of what Sets are, and the spread syntax. Since the OP was already using `reduce` this seemed easier :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` for that

First you create an object with the value of `a` as key and you group all `b` with the same `a`

Then you simply remove the object keys using `Object.values`

```js
const array = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Bar']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
]

const grouped =  Object.values(array.reduce(
  (res, {a, b}) => {
    const existing = res[a] || {b: []}
    return {
      ...res,
      [a]: {a, b: [...existing.b, ...b]}
    }
  }, {}
))

console.log(grouped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce you can merge the values of b and create a new array.

```js
const array = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Bar']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
];

const result = array.reduce((t, { a, b }, _, arr) => {
  if (t.some(v => v.a === a))
    return t; // if a is already handled, skip
  return [
    ...t,
    {
      a,
      b: arr
        .filter(v => v.a === a) // filter out items with different "a" value
        .reduce((t, v) => [...t, ...v.b], []), // merge the values of "b"
    }
  ];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use `Set` to make sure no duplicate values. And finally `map` it back to an array.

```js
const array = [
  {a: 1, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Bar']},
  {a: 1, b: ['Baz']},
  {a: 2, b: ['Foo']},
  {a: 3, b: ['Foo']},
]

const o = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if(!(acc[obj?.a] instanceof Set))
    acc[obj.a] = new Set()
  acc[obj.a].add(obj.b)
  return acc
}, {})

const result = Object.entries(o).map(([a, b]) => ({a, b: Array.from(b) }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript `Map`

```js
const array = [
  { a: 1, b: ["Foo"] },
  { a: 1, b: ["Bar"] },
  { a: 1, b: ["Baz"] },
  { a: 2, b: ["Foo"] },
  { a: 3, b: ["Foo"] },
];

const grouped = Array.from(
  array
    .reduce((m, o) => {
      if (m.has(o.a)) {
        const currObj = m.get(o.a);
        m.set(o.a, { ...currObj, b: [...currObj.b, ...o.b] });
      } else {
        m.set(o.a, o);
      }
      return m;
    }, new Map())
    .values()
);

console.log(grouped);
```